# wpf VisualTreeHelper.HitTest

Tags: wpf

I have a canvas and within it I have many Thumbs..
when I make a hit test on the canvas so as to find the thumbs near my mouse I get the wrong 
expected result which I get the border of the thumb not the thumb itself..

Please I want the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    
class HotPoint:Thumb, IDraggable
    {
    ...
    }
    IDraggable hotpoint = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(result.VisualHit) as IDraggable;
```

Where IDraggable is an Interface I inherit from with the thumb. I remembered that every  hotpoint has a custom control template so when I do hit tests the search will be on the primitive types, so when  I get the parent of that object it will solve my request.